# How to define a conditional property with a variable sub property name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a configuration property class that contains a map. The map is filled with values from a yml file. the structure looks like this.

```
config:
  variable_sub_key_a:
    key_a: 1234
    key_b: 1234
  variable_sub_key_b:
...
```

The configuration class looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration{
 private Map<String, KEY> config= new HashMap<>();
}
```

I would like that the configuration class is only initialized by spring when the config element exists in the yml file. My problem is that a part of the property name can vary. So i can't use @ConditionalOnProperty. I tried it with different contidional-annotations but haven't found out how i could define a conditional that checks only that the property starts with config.* . Any hints how i can do this?

Comment: Isn't it possible to collect to `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`? Still you need to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on `config`

Comment: i don't think that would help. The problem is that i have to know the full key like "config.variable_sub_key_a.key_a". I would like to define a configuration class that could contain generic property names.

Comment: @sge look into Condition Interface. Implement the Condition Interface write your logic. then use @Conditional(value=class which implements the condition interface).                    https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan thanks, i've already tried to implement my own condition. There i haven't found a way to get  a list of propertynames that are defined in the yml file. i could read the yml file by myself but then i have to implement the logic inheritence logic as well.

Comment: Which part of the configuration key can change?

Comment: it's variable_sub_key_a. this part of the property name can vary

Comment: @sge in the matches method implemented from condition interface, try  YamlPropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = AlienYamlPropertiesFactoryBeanFactory.get(context.getResourceLoader());  then to get data use propertiesFactoryBean.getObject().   and apply your logic

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan thanks for your hint but i don't want use a thirdparty library for this functionality.

Comment: @sge I didn't get you about third party. YamlPropertiesFactoryBean is part of spring framework.   https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan i meant AlienYamlPropertiesFactoryBeanFactory is a third party library